# AppImage not working

Tags: 18.04, mount, fuse

I am using a dev tool for working with mongodb. It was working fine yesterday. when I came today I get this error while running the appImage in terminal

```
fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
```

I normally call it using terminal by going over to my downloads directory then hitting the command

```
./nosqlbooster4mongo*.AppImage
```

I looked over the internet but couldn't find a satisfactory solution. I am extremely new to ubuntu, so maybe I did something wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After hours of searching found the solution!
This happens with fuse. Instead of this

```
./nosqlbooster4mongo*.AppImage
```

I added an extra clause of

```
--appimage-extract-and-run
```

Now you can run your appImage like

```
./nosqlbooster4mongo*.AppImage --appimage-extract-and-run
```

Hope this helps anyone else who faces this issue!

Comment: Helped me run Mbed Studio on Ubuntu 22.04. Just did `mbed-studio --appimage-extract-and-run` from user account and voila.