# Appimage not running

Tags: 20.04

When trying to run an Appimage, I get the following error - 
Something went wrong trying to read the squashfs image.

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory

When I try the solution given in -[AppImage not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188938/appimage-not-working)

I get the following error -
Something went wrong trying to read the squashfs image.
Failed to open squashfs image
Failed to extract AppImage

Please help.

Comment: I think your Appimage file is corrupt. Tried redownloading and installing? And also give permissions to the file. sudo chmod +rwx filename.Appimage

Comment: Yes, the appimage itself is problematic. As I tried running after upgrading to 20.04, I assumed the problem was not there. Other appimages are running fine.